# How do I decrease the size of the Ionic Android APK file?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I created the app using Ionic and the Android APK file size is too big.

Before the API integration The File Size was 4.8MB. When I integrated the API I modified just 10 Pages now the APK file size is 71 MB.

Here are the Cordova Plugins I have used:

- `cordova-plugin-console`
- `cordova-plugin-datepicker`
- `cordova-plugin-device`
- `cordova-plugin-network-information`
- `cordova-plugin-splashscreen`
- `cordova-plugin-statusbar`
- `cordova-plugin-whitelist`
- `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing`
- `cordova-sqlite-storage`
- `es6-promise-plugin`
- `ionic-plugin-keyboard`

I unzipped the APK file to find out what going on. I looked at the `build` Folder in `assets/www/` folder which alone was 357MB and it contains JavaScript and MAP files and a 4.5MB CSS file.

How do I decrease the size of the Ionic Android APK file?

Comment: how are you generating it? are you using `--prod` flag?

Comment: I'm Not using --prod .I'll Check It Again anyway Thanx

Comment: I recently find out some version of keyboard module is too huge. Just check it once.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use the `--prod` and `--release` flags when building the APK file for production. It reduces the size by compressing the files.

```
ionic build android --prod --release
```

Answer (score 6):

For people running into that issue with newer versions of Ionic:

In **Ionic 4.3** there seems to be a bug in the build scripts. If you run a debug build, and then a release/production build, the `www` folder is not cleared and you will have all the sourcemap (.js.map) files in the www folder and thus in the final apk file.

See https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3954

Answer (score 4):

Please use below command:
    `ionic cordova build android --minifycss --optimizejs --minifyjs --release
[note:- "ionic cordova build android --prod --release" command have email pattern matching issue in a form, always give invalid email error hence not used that command]`
Use below link for more details:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug (not sure) but when live reload is active, the tree shaking feature causes the build to emit several chunk files into the `www` folder and i think the more you reload, the more files you'd have in there.

So you'd see files in the form

```
0.7f0f403f3c9f5914fbce.js
0.7f0f403f3c9f5914fbce.js.map
1.0db885b5a44ebd4ca57e.js
1.0db885b5a44ebd4ca57e.js.map
...and the number goes 0, 1, 2, ... n
```

You simply need to delete the `www` folder to discard the stale chunk files and rebuild your app.

The apk size should be justifiable after that.

Answer (score 2):

Run `cordova clean` to cleanup project from build artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps

1. ng build --prod
2. delete www before building from root folder
3. ionic cordova build android --prod --release

Answer (score 0):

check `sourceMap` in `angular.json` if `true` put it in `false`

Answer (score 0):

I think I am a little late to answer but I here are some of my observations:

Ways to reduce production APK.

1. Make sure you have created a production build before creating APK
   Use this command in order to create prod build

   ```
   ng build --prod
   ```
2. Now use the below command to open android studio for further steps

   ```
   ionic capacitor run android --prod
   //--prod is optional if you have already performed step 1
   ```
3. You can set `minifyEnabled` to minify the code which will also reduce the size of the APK drastically.
4. There is one more thing that I have tried, once you have created a prod build you can delete the unused SVGs from the android source folder. I believe that is added in the assets and so in the prod APK.
   (Though the step 4 is I am not sure is safe to perform but it did not harm me in anyway) :)

I have seen the size has been reduced from 4.2 MB to 3.4 MB using step 4 ;)

Those are the steps I have performed to reduce the size of the ionic APKs.

Happy Coding!!