# IONIC 4 empty project android apk file size big

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have developed the app using ionic 4 and created new tab app and build android apk file it 's size getting way too big.

App Size Was 6177kB

```
"@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IONIC Android Apk File size Way Too Big ! how to decrease the size of app for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988174/ionic-android-apk-file-size-way-too-big-how-to-decrease-the-size-of-app-for-an)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delete www folder from your project and then try to build.